# Can't save ManyToManyField

Tags: python, django, forms

So the problem is that I can't save ManyToManyField from form.

Here is my form:
forms.py

```
class addGoods(forms.Form):
   ...

    permission = form['permission'],

   ...
```

My model: models.py

```
class Add_good(models.Model):
   ...

    permission = models.ManyToManyField(Permission, related_name="+")

   ...
```

In my view if request method equals "POST", I try to save these data into my model: views.py

```
if request.method == "POST":
    form = addGoods(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():

        form = form.cleaned_data
        newGood = Add_good(permission = form['permission'])
```

I have tried to do something like this(see below), but there is also errors:
views.py

```
if request.method == "POST":
        form = addGoods(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():

            form = form.cleaned_data
            newGood = Add_good(permission = form['permission'])

            to_do_list = newGood.save(commit=False)
            for permis in form['permission']:
                to_do_list.permission.add(permis)
                to_do_list.save()
            newGood.save_m2m()
```

And my traceback 
Traceback:

```
Exception Type: TypeError at /goods/add
Exception Value: 'permission' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

So as you can see there is something wrong with `permission` and I can't save it

Comment: @khajvah add traceback

Comment: Well, the error is about different issue. You have not posted enough code to find it. Where does 'permission' come from?

Comment: @khajvah sorry edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here: 
`newGood = Add_good(permission = form['permission'])`

Permission is ManyToMany field, so your table doesn't directly have `permision` field, so it can't take that argument. You can create the model entry then add the permission:

```
newGood = Add_good.objects.create(...)
newGood.permission.add(Permissions.objects.get(...))
```

Also, your form won't make models from permissions as you just did `permission = form['permission']`, so you will need to make a manual query in your view instead of/in the for loop.